# Custom Unwind Seque

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, segue, uistoryboardsegue

In my project I have a view controller that reacts to a left to right swipe on the screen by performing a custom segue that animates like so:

```
-(void)perform {
    UIViewController *sourceViewController = (UIViewController*)[self sourceViewController];
    UIViewController *destinationController = (UIViewController*)[self destinationViewController];

    CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = .25;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;

    [sourceViewController.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition

    [sourceViewController.navigationController pushViewController:destinationController animated:NO];
}
```

Basically this allows the user to slide between the chatroom interface and a settings view controller. Currently I have created an unwind segue the traditional way by control dragging from the settings button to the exit button on the storyboard and implementing this function in my chat room view controller (where they return to on a right to left swipe):

```
-(IBAction)unwindFromLeft:(UIStoryboardSegue *)seque {

}
```

This works fine to get back to the view controller. However what I really want is the view controller to animate sliding in from the right, however it slides in from the left like a normal unwind segue. Therefore my question is, how can implement a custom animation that changes how the unwind segue performs, e.g. make the view controller I am unwinding to, slide in from right to left.

Comment: If you use a modal view you can then pop the view and it will pop with the correct animation direction.

Comment: Unfortunately I want to maintain the navigation bar when the user enters the settings page, it does some animation that I would like to keep in the app, is there a way to make a custom class for the unwind segue that I could then animate in a way I wanted?

Comment: I added a custom CATransition, it's ugly but it gets the job done for now.